# Is it possible to rename Status options (Active/Inactive) of a Custom Entity?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics

I've a custom entity, Fee. For the `status reason` of this entity I've already modify `Inactive` to `Processed`. Now I want to rename its `inactive status` option to `Completed`.

Is it possible or any workaround to this will be handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no out of box way to do this.
But there is a Trick.
You can export Translation for Statecode (Active/Inactive) and in label change it to whatever you like and then reimport it to CRM. This shall reflect the changes.

I just tried this in one of my demo instance on Account Entity. I changed Inactive to Inactive Test and it did reflected.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply, will this impact all State Code values for all entities?

Comment: It affects only that entity for which you translated and not complete system

Comment: I used this XML Tool Box plugin and works for me. `https://www.xrmtoolbox.com/plugins/MsCrmTools.Translator/` 

Thank you  for valuable suggestion